# how to validate all groups on hibernate validator?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations

I have this model which i want to validate:

```
public class ClientDomain {

    public interface AddValidations {
    }

    public interface UpdateValidations {
    }

    private String id;

    @NotNull(groups = {ClientDomain.AddValidations.class})
    @Size(min = 2, max = 10, groups = {ClientDomain.AddValidations.class})
    private String name;

    @NotNull(groups = {ClientDomain.UpdateValidations.class})
    private ClientType type;

    @NotNull(groups = {ClientDomain.AddValidations.class})
    private Gender gender;

.....
}
```

Then, i am validating it like this:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = this.validator.validate(clientDomain);
```

This is not working, as far i know that is because all constraints validations belong to certains groups, then when i don't pass a group to validate, the validator takes by default the javax.validation.group.Default, then it validates nothing, i am right? if so, then is there any way to validate all constraints validations regardless the group they belong to? Regards!

PD: Obviusly, i do not want to do this:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = this.validator.validate(clientDomain, ClientDomain.AddValidations, ClientDomain.UpdateValidations);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about use inheritance for it?

If `ClientDomain` is your parent interface. You can do this:

>> when:

```
public interface ClientDomain extends Default {} 
public interface AddValidation extends ClientDomain
public interface UpdateValidation extends ClientDomain
```

>> then

```
 @NotNull(groups = {UpdateValidations.class})
 private ClientType type;

 @NotNull
 private Gender gender;
```

In this example, `Gender` is mandatory constraint for both groups. `ClientType` on the other hand is only for `UpdateValidation`. You will write less code and it is more clean to read also.

Btw. `ClientDomain` is not necessary in this example. This is just for better imagination to show what you can do with this.

More details: [hibernate validator docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e1860)

Comment: thanks! i thought there was another without modifying interfaces. But this is not bad at last. Regards

Comment: You are very welcome! Honestly, I think that this approach is really good. Interfaces are used as simple marking interfaces and working as validation aspects. That way, you have clean separation between Data and Constraints.